# BreezeJs - Concurrency Save Changes from Multi-Devices

Tags: concurrency, breeze, durandal, device

I am writing a SPA app that can be used on many devices by the same user. Say there are two entities E1 et E2 and two different users U1 and U2 logged in with the same account on the app. While U1 is adding/modifying/deleting on E1, U2 is also adding/modifying/deleting on E2. Then U2 saves E2 changes, E1 remaining unchanged on his device. Now, problem is when U1 saves E1 changes, E2 changes that U2 saved get overwritten by the initial E2 state that is on U1's device. My question is, how does we keep Breeze from overwriting changes that were made from another device if the entity is unchanged on ours? Practical example would be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether the server implementation that you are using supports the concept of optimistic concurrency.  With Breeze's .NET/Entity Framework/WebApi2  server which does support optimistic concurrency, breeze's saves will fail for any entity where the concurrency value for that entity has changed since it was last read.  Breeze's server impl automatically updates this concurrency value with each save.

So with your example, Users U1 and U2 will both read in the same entity E1 with a concurrency value of say 'X'. When U1 attempts to save, the update checks that the current E1 concurrency value is in fact 'X' before the save is allowed to continue. In this case because U1 is first, the save succeeds and E1's concurrency value gets automatically updated to 'X2'.

Now when U2 attempts to save, the save will fail because the current E1 concurrency value of 'X2' does not match U2's copy of E1 which still has a concurrency value of 'X'.  When a save fails the entire transaction is rolled back and an optimistic concurrency error is reported to the client.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Thank you, Jay. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score -1):

Breeze does not support concurrent saves defaultly. If you want concurrent save enable this option in while calling before saveChanges function in breeze..

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
    dataservice: "api/Todo",
    saveOptions: new breeze.SaveOptions({allowConcurrentSaves: true})
});
```

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/concurrent-saves

Comment: You have not understood the question correctly, it means that you have 2 clients making changes to the same entity. What you state is the funcionality for saving multiple entities on the same client, which is a completely different thing.